# When are the "Automatic Optional Chain Completions" triggered in VS Code?

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code

VS Code 1.40 has two new settings `javascript.suggest.includeAutomaticOptionalChainCompletions` and `typescript.suggest.includeAutomaticOptionalChainCompletions` and I understand these are supposed to enable or disable the suggestions of [optional chain completions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) by suggesting `?.` completions. What I don't understand is when these `?.` completions would be triggered. I've set these two settings to true and I'm using TypeScript 3.8, but when I write the following code:

```
const adventurer = {
    name: 'Alice',
    cat: {
        name: 'Dinah'
    }
};

const dogName = adventurer.dog?.
```

I don't get automatic optional chain completion after `dog?.`.

So what's the use case for the `javascript.suggest.includeAutomaticOptionalChainCompletions` and `typescript.suggest.includeAutomaticOptionalChainCompletions` settings in VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

Optional chain completion isn't working in VS Code v1.40. It's working in Insiders v1.41.0 but now you can't turn it off. There's a [bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85015) on this.

Also, optional chain completions are triggered on `const dogName = adventurer?.` not `const dogName = adventurer.dog?.`